# Best way to link to categories from static blocks

Tags: magento, url, categories, permalinks

What is the best way to link to categories and products from static blocks.

I ask because sometimes we will update URL-keys for categories, etc, which will break links in static blocks to given categories and products.

Is there a better way to link using ids etc so the links will be active regardless of seo-friendly urls?

Currently, I use links such as:
`<a href="store.com/generators/generators.html?"generator_package=6>link</a>`

When the urls for the categories change the above link would be broken.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Let me know the result, maybe we can handle other ways.

**+++ EDIT - New Code Sample +++**
First create a static block which is this block should reference a phtml file that you can put your logic into this file.

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/ListCategory.phtml"}}
```

Create ListCategory.phtml in the /app/design/frontend/[YOUR_THEME]/template/catalog/category/ directory.

```
<?php
// get current category id
$curCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

// instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
$category = Mage::getModel(catalog/category)->load((int)$curCategory);

// child category id array
$childCategories = $category->getChildren();

?>
```

Comment: unfortunately it prints this on the frontend: load(6)->getUrl() ?>">Link

Comment: @vulgarbulgar try this new one.